# How to insert my junit test result to database in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a question about jenkins. I am triggering ant script on jenkins. Ant is compiling,testing,exporting java. I need to insert test result on my database. How can i do that? Can I insert test result in ant script? Can I insert test result in jenkins?

Comment: Any particular reason you need to insert results into your database? I would consider using Sonarqube  (See: https://www.sonarqube.org/). This is a tool designed to integrate with your build workflow, with plugins available for ANT and Jenkins. All results stored in a database, with a web based frontend for analysis and sharing. Much better when compared to creating something bespoke

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql db plugin.
Audit db plugin
Or connect to db through execute shell in post build action of test job to run the query to insert the result.

Comment: I trıed to connect audıt db plugın but I encountered an error "org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
JDBC Driver class : com.mysql.jdbc.Drive
JDBC Url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
user : root  when I clıcked test connectıon button I saw this error